# Read single second level JSON entry with Ionic

Tags: json, ionic-framework

I've got this JSON file that I'm trying to parse the second level off. But it seems to fail.

```
{
  "error":false,
  "accessToken":"xxx",
  "accountId":"xxx",
  "account":[
  {
    "error":false,
    "id":"2",,
    "username":"Username"
  }]
}
```

Here's the Ionic code

```
return $http.post(SERVER.apiUrl + SERVER.apiLogin,
{username: "username",password: "password"})
.success(function(data){
    o.setSession(data.accountId, data.accessToken, data.account[0]["username"]);
});
```

Error

```
TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined
at services.js:103
at ionic.bundle.js:17151
at processQueue (ionic.bundle.js:20962)
at ionic.bundle.js:20978
at Scope.$eval (ionic.bundle.js:22178)
at Scope.$digest (ionic.bundle.js:21994)
at Scope.$apply (ionic.bundle.js:22282)
at done (ionic.bundle.js:17439)
at completeRequest (ionic.bundle.js:17629)
at XMLHttpRequest.requestLoaded (ionic.bundle.js:17570)
```

i have also tried with

```
data.account.username
```

and

```
data.account[0].username
```

Can anybody give a quick advice?

Best regards

Answer (score 0):

do not understand why it does not work for you, I tried it and does not give me problems.
Although at least here, you put two commas after ID

```
data.account[0]["username"]    Is Ok
```

```
{
  "error":false,
  "accessToken":"xxx",
  "accountId":"xxx",
  "account":[
  {
    "error":false,
    "id":"2",,  <-- ERROR
    "username":"Username"
  }]
}
```

Comment: I think it's because I need to save it as a variable first, however this seems not to be possible in the following code

return $http.post(SERVER.url + SERVER.apiLogin, {        username: "username",
                                                         password: "Password"
                                                        }).success(function(data){
            userName = data.account[0]["username"]
            o.setSession(data.accessToken, userName, data.account.fullname, "success:ok");
            
        })

Comment: you parse it? / 
data = JSON.parse(data);